# how to connect to GPIO connectors if they are already occupied

Tags: gpio, pi-zero-w, shutdown

I want to connect 2 wires to the connectors to put pysical shutdown button,
like showed [here](https://embeddedcomputing.com/technology/open-source/development-kits/raspberry-pi-power-up-and-shutdown-with-a-physical-button)

But the connector will be already occpuied by e-paper driver.

[image]

What would be a recommendation here?
Just to solder the wires and put e-paper driver board on top of those? or is there a better solution?

Comment: You could use a PCB with a stackable connector like this: https://thepihut.com/products/40-pin-extra-tall-header-push-fit-version-no-shroud or https://eu.robotshop.com/products/prototyping-hat-raspberry-pi-zero

Comment: @Bodo thanks! Do you mean I can put long connector so I have space to put something in between the connector and the e-paper driver? If yes, is there a small "through" single pins so I can put them in between to attach the button? Or do you mean I should just solder the wires in that between space?

Comment: You could use such a stackable connector or a PCB with this connector between the Pi and the other board and solder wires to this intermediate thing. As there seems to be space, you could also wire-wrap wires to the pins of the Pi if you want to avoid soldering. Example photos https://qph.cf2.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-c825e0d1f79e012943d3a3624705ac4b or https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41Tab1l3YeL.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect something else to the GPIOs you have the following options:

- Use [stackable pin header](https://www.reichelt.de/raspberry-pi-stacking-header-40-polig-rm-2-54-rpi-header-40-p223626.html?PROVID=2788&gclid=Cj0KCQiApKagBhC1ARIsAFc7Mc6tP7qfNA9nfUlbc2s4kdmGva-qgM6Iqflg6gSOJD0ROxQvlVLcRcoaAnpGEALw_wcB) (or [the 90 degree one](https://www.reichelt.de/raspberry-pi-gpio-header-1-auf-2-40-polig-rm-2-54-rpi-gpio-1to2-p276993.html?PROVID=2788&gclid=Cj0KCQiApKagBhC1ARIsAFc7Mc5wUGIPS6Gf7TOI5OiT2hDyhs0SXp6KUj_fR6MXa_zu5IL3RAk1uocaArD4EALw_wcB)) between the boards you show and solder your button to it.
- Use PCB with stackable pin headers and a button (e.g. make it yourself using [a breakout PCB](https://www.mouser.de/ProductDetail/Pimoroni/PIM300?qs=lc2O%252BfHJPVa%2FmFi4aqpGcQ%3D%3D&mgh=1&vip=1&gclid=Cj0KCQiApKagBhC1ARIsAFc7Mc6p3PrM8eY8m09AHj95S1A-FjlCkeyzf8r6SzoncFblTJ3BLZrSpCMaApSeEALw_wcB) and headers from above), put the PCB between the boards
- Solder the button connections to one of the boards. You may solder at the same locations where the pin headers are soldered.
- Since pins are quite long, you can try to figure out something to connect to the pin in the space between the boards (e.g. [wire wrap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wire_wrap) would've been a good option, but it is a challenge without proper tooling and skills)

There are definitely number of other possibilities that applicability would depend on your requirements for space, accessibility, esthetic, mechanical load and etc.

In any case pay attention to the GPIOs used for the display, the button **should not** use the same ones.